# How to parse CSV to Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am using .csv-files and want to parse them so I can insert the strings/ content of my csv-file into the different tables. I searched on the Internet and found this [tweet](https://twitter.com/mgoricki/status/1051135981049577472). Then I tried to adapt the code to my problem and this is how it currently looks like:

```
select /*csv*/ * from uploaded_files where filename LIKE 'I%_Trigger.csv';
with 
    function get_column (p_row varchar2, p_col_num number)
    return varchar2
    is 
    v_row apex_t_varchar2;
    begin
    v_row := apex_string.split(p_row, ';');
    if v_row.exists(p_col_num) then
        return v_row(p_col_num);
    end if;
    return null;
    end;

select get_column(column_value, 1) as col1,
        get_column(column_value, 2) as col2,
        get_column(column_value, 3) as col3,
        get_column(column_value, 4) as col4,
        get_column(column_value, 5) as col5,
        get_column(column_value, 6) as col6,
        get_column(column_value, 7) as col7,
        get_column(column_value, 8) as col8
    from apex_string.split(:CSVDATA, chr(10));
```

To shortly explain my code: uploaded_files stores the .csv-files. The table contains a column named file_blob which stores the content of the file. I have to convert it to clob (that part is missing here) to be able to parse the data.

When I am running the code I am getting the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl wurde nicht korrekt beendet
>
> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

I think the error has to do something with the last line. Can anyone explain what `:CSVDATA` does mean in the tweet? Ok, I know that it contains the data of my csv but what exactly is it and how is it declared/ defined? What does the `:` mean in this context?

Comment: I am using Oracle version 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: Would you consider using Oracle's SQL Loader to do all the loading and parsing, instead of storing the file in a blob and parsing it out yourself? SQL Loader is built to handle delimited files.

Comment: Actually I have never heard of the Oracle SQL Loader so far, but maybe this is a good hint. I shortly explain you my current situation so you can understand why I tried to parse it on my own: I am programming an apex webapplication. For the user it would be the userfriendliest way to import the data by dragging and dropping the .csv-files into a dropzone. After clicking a button the data should be inserted into the tables. The uploading via dropzone works so far and now I want to insert the data. That is actually why I am currently parsing the data on my own.

Comment: Is a similar solution possible with the SQL Loader? The most important thing is to provide a solution, so that a normal user who has no programming skills is able to import the data.

Comment: SQL Loader is mostly used with bulk data loads and wouldn't probably be the best solution here (you'd need to install Oracle Client software and handle a lot of configuration). How are you running the code? `:CSVDATA` is a _bind variable_ which you need to assign data into. In the SQLDeveloper worksheet there is a popup dialog that allows you to do this when you run the query. Also note that the script has two parts: the top-row `SELECT` which gets you the data you need to feed into the bind variable and the main query that starts with the `WITH function..` clause.

Comment: From where you're at, you may like to consider my responses here https://community.oracle.com/message/14965110#14965110 I load CSVs regularly, converting them to table data using Excel2Collection PL/SQL plugin.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: In Oracle APEX you have the opportunity to "connect" your button with the PL/SQL Code. By clicking on to the button the code should be run. If I am understanding you correctly, I have to  write one PL/ SQL code block and not need two parts as I it is now.

Comment: @Scott: I had a look at the plugin, but  as far as I understand the plugin it is for parsing xlxs files. Will this also work for .csv-files?

Comment: So, can you run the script okay as two separate statements? If so, it's then just a matter of wrapping this inside a PL/SQL procedure/block.

Comment: Running the script in two separate statements might be possible, but if I can do it in only one it would be great. Isn't it possible to store the first select-statement in a variable and then move on with the second part? Then we don't have two parts/ statements.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What I meant is: do you get an error if you now run the statements separately?

Comment: Yep, it works for csv as well. Multi-worksheet excel files are a welcome bonus.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: Yes, I do get an error code if I run the statements separately. The error appears after running the second statement. "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: :CSVDATA in the tweet refers to the values he copied from the grid in SQL Developer from the results of the first statement. In the video the first statement is SELECT * FROM emp. Run as a script SQL Developer returns comma separated values. So you would just need to get the data from your statement into the place where :CSVDATA is.